# How to MOQ Sitecore User object?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sitecore, moq, sitecore8

I need to do Moq test for the below original method

```
public virtual User GetBOUser(string domainName, string userName, string password, Login model)
{
    try
    {
        if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Exists(domainName + @"\" + userName))
        {
            User user = Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(domainName + @"\" + userName, true);
            return user;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.Error("GetBOUser Error - " + ex.ToString(), this);
    }

    return null;
}
```

The sample unit test method I have created is below

```
[TestMethod]
public void LoginApiTest()
{            
    User use = null;            

    var mockapi = new Mock<ApiController>();
    mockapi.Setup(x => x.GetBOUser("", "", "", new Login())).Returns(use);

    var dataObject = mockapi.Object;

    Assert.AreEqual<User>(use, dataObject.GetBOUser("", "", "", new Login()));
}
```

Here I am able to check only for null in the return type of test method, But how to return a actual `user` object ?

Answer (score 3):

Before I address your question, I need to point out that your sample test is not actually testing anything.  You are mocking your system under test, telling it to return null and then asserting that it returned null.  This will not execute your production code.

You should be creating a normal instance of your ApiController.  However, that highlights another issue in that your method has a dependency on Sitecore's static security API.  If you want your code to be testable, you will need to create an interface and wrapper class for that API and make your controller accept an instance of your interface in its constructor so that you can provide a mock instance for your test but a real instance in production.

Your wrapper class should only call the static API and should contain no logic.  That way you don't really need to test it.  When you set up the mock instance of your interface you can create a mock IPrincipal and pass it to User.FromPrincipal to prevent it from actually trying to lookup the user in the database.  If you were to name your interface IUserService, your test would end up looking something like this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetBOUser_WithExistingUser_ReturnsUser()
{
    // Arrange
    var name = "Joe";
    var domain = "extranet";
    var fullName = domain + @"\" + name;

    var principal = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
    principal.Setup(p => p.Identity.Name).Returns(fullName);
    var joeUser = User.FromPrincipal(principal);

    var userService = new Mock<IUserService>();
    userService.Setup(u => u.Exists(fullName)).Returns(true);
    userService.Setup(u => u.FromName(fullName)).Returns(joeUser.Object);

    var controller = new ApiController(userService.Object);

    // Act
    var result = controller.GetBOUser("extranet", "Joe", "password", new Login());

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(fullName, result.Name);
}
```

One other thing... Your GetBOUser method accepts a password, but does not validate it before returning a user.  That is very misleading to consumers of your API.  If you accept a password you should make sure it is correct before returning the requested user object.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ben, Your answer is really really helpful and i can able to achieve the test. Thanks